# Access web server on VPN client through VPN server public IP

Tags: vpn, openvpn, port-forwarding, forwarding

I am trying to access a web server running on a PC, that is behind a firewall not managed by me, using a VPN connection (openvpn). Basically, I want to use the public ip of my VPN server for accessing the web server on the remote PC behind the firewall.

As per image,http://193.105.1.1:8085 will present the web site hosted at 192.168.1.1:8080

[image: Network]

Sorry if this question has already been addressed. I have tried to search something similar, but I actually do not know what to search.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough!

For ease let's Consider Machine A - 193.105.1.1 & Machine B - 192.168.1.1

1. Install OpenVPN server on the Machine A

   I prefer Ubuntu 18.04 and Nyr OpenVPN Installer Script

   Just run this in terminal

   `wget https://git.io/vpn -O openvpn-install.sh && bash openvpn-install.sh`
2. Assuming you already have apache or nginx setup on Machine B, make sure it listens to all interfaces.
3. On Machine B install OpenVPN client to connect to your server!

   Run this code in terminal to install OpenVPN Client

   `sudo apt-get install openvpn`
4. We need to now configure Machine A to route traffic from the public IP to the OpenVPN internal IP address, Machine B will be alloted address 10.8.0.2 if you used the Nyr Script.

Let's Configure the routing!

1. Enable ufw firewall
2. `sudo ufw enable ssh && sudo ufw enable`
3. `sudo nano /etc/default/ufw`
4. Change "DEFAULT_INPUT_POLICY" and "DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY" to ACCEPT. Save and close the file.
5. `sudo nano /etc/ufw/sysctl.conf`
6. Uncomment n"et/ipv4/ip_forward=1". Save and close the file.
7. `sudo nano /etc/ufw/before.rules`
8. At the end of line after the line ""COMMIT" add the following

   *nat

   -F

   :PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

   -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 193.105.1.1 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 23:65535 -j  DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2

   -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 ! -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE

   COMMIT

Change eth0 to your network interface name.

Save and reboot both server!
Connect Machine B to Machine A by OpenVPN client.

Comment: OP states that one machine is not managed by him/her.  That would present a challenge to your solution.

Comment: Which machine are you running the commands in "Configure the routing!" from?